# web api function throwing exception of System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-entities

I am calling the below code in my api from a mobile device and from a Rest client:

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("api/mobile/GetUsersList")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetUsersList()
        {

            var users = from c in db.Users
                            select new { c.id, c.user_name, c.reports_to };


            return Ok(users.ToList());

        }
```

I get an error of:

> The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type

I am not using a where so I'm not sure why this simple query would throw this error.

I am testing the Http GET to this function using Advanced Rest Client.

I see in other SO posts that this error gets thrown when a where parameter is null.

Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to specify name directly with cast

```
var users = from c in db.Users
            select new { id= (int?)c.id, user_name = c.user_name, reports_to = c.reports_to };
```

or

```
id = c.id ?? 0
```

Comment: Roman Marusyk I modified my code to reflect your suggestion and cast but I am still getting the same error in my original question.

Comment: Are `user_name` and `reports_to` string?

Comment: user_name is a string and reports_to is a string. Thinking about that now, reports_to could be null.

Comment: @Ryan any results?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Entity FrameWork and dependency injection to grab the data by doing something like this:

```
 public async Task<List<User>> GetUsersList()
        {
            return await _context.Users.ToListAsync();
        }
```

Here are some resources to Entity framework:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/async

Comment: @Ricky09 I am using EF. The "db" in db.Users is the DBContext.